# Running TestNG programmatically, getting the "Cannot find class in classpath" exception

Tags: java, classpath, testng

I am trying to run TestNG programmatically using the Virtual XML, as described here:
http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#running-testng-programmatically

Here is my code:

```
        TestListenerAdapter tla = new TestListenerAdapter();
        TestNG tng = new TestNG();
        tng.addListener(tla);

        XmlSuite suite = new XmlSuite();
        suite.setName("Retry Suite");

        for (ITestResult testResult : failedTests){
            XmlTest xmlTest = new XmlTest(suite);
            //xmlTest.setSuite(suite);
            xmlTest.setName(testResult.getTestName());

            List<XmlClass> xmlClasses = new ArrayList<>();
            xmlClasses.add(new XmlClass(testResult.getTestClass().getXmlClass().toString()));
            xmlTest.setXmlClasses(xmlClasses);

            xmlTest.getClasses().addAll(xmlClasses);
            suite.addTest(xmlTest);
        }

        List<XmlSuite> suites = new ArrayList<>();
        suites.add(suite);
        tng.setXmlSuites(suites);
        tng.run();
```

I get the following exception when the code reaches the block:

```
[ERROR] org.testng.TestNGException:
[ERROR] Cannot find class in classpath: [XmlClass class=tests.system.browserTests.BrowserTests]
[ERROR] at org.testng.xml.XmlClass.loadClass(XmlClass.java:81)
[ERROR] at org.testng.xml.XmlClass.init(XmlClass.java:73)
[ERROR] at org.testng.xml.XmlClass.init(XmlClass.java:63)
[ERROR] at org.testng.xml.XmlClass.<init>(XmlClass.java:39)
[ERROR] at tests.utils.autoReport.postHandler.TestNGLiseteners.retrySuiteVirtXml(TestNGLiseteners.java:226)
[ERROR] at tests.utils.autoReport.postHandler.TestNGLiseteners.onExecutionFinish(TestNGLiseteners.java:204)
```

I cannot figure out why? Any ideas?

Comment: It seems that you are not instantiating correctly XmlClass here "new XmlClass(testResult.getTestClass().getXmlClass().toString())". Try new XmlClass(testResult.getTestClass())

Comment: @RubioRic the XmlClass constructor accepts String, while testResult.getTestClass() returns IClass. Anyway, even with .toString() it results in the same exception.

Comment: Invoke getName on IClass instead of toString.

Comment: @RubioRic cool! Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that you are not instantiating correctly XmlClass in this line

```
new XmlClass(testResult.getTestClass().getXmlClass().toString())
```

Use instead

```
new XmlClass(testResult.getTestClass().getName())
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your `.project` file should contain at minimum:

```
</projects>
    <buildSpec>
        <buildCommand>
            <name>org.eclipse.jdt.core.javabuilder</name>
            <arguments>
            </arguments>
        </buildCommand>
    </buildSpec>
    <natures>
        <nature>org.eclipse.jdt.core.javanature</nature>
    </natures>
```

Also check availability of compiled classes in the output directory by default `/bin`

PS. For standard java project